# Having a path issue uploading photos in my nodejs app

Tags: node.js, image, path, portfolio

I saved all my photos inside a folder named public and portPics because
they are screenshots of my work that I'm putting into a slideshow.
However. in my index.hbs (using express-handlebars) I have a 
the code right here below

```
<img src="./../public/portPic/
```

however I tried debugging, doing ./ and then no dot. then right clicking and pasting the full path.
I have no idea why its not taking the photos, It even says file cannot be found when I post a pdf file with the download tag.

Hopefully it's something small I went over too quick. 
This is for my portfolio please help!

Comment: Post some more code. It will depend on your file structure, if possible post that screenshot as well

Comment: If you have a logger attached to the express server, check the path of routes that are getting accessed. As your image is not visible, express with show `404` for some path. Compare that path with other paths.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I got it now! THANKS

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't posted more code or screenshot of the file structure, I'm going to take a shot in dark.

`../` will give you current directory. As you go on adding `../`, you will go to upper directories.

`./` will give you application's root directory.

I don't think you can use `./` and `../` together

If you have a logger attached to the express server, check the path of routes that are getting accessed. If you don't have a logger, try [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan)

As your image is not visible, express with show `404` for some path. Compare that path with the other paths. This will show you where its going wrong.